# Regular curves and 1-dimensional manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curves

This is probably a silly question but I want to understand why regular curves are 1-dimensional manifolds, something mentioned in several books. I assume they mean the trace of a curve, so let $\gamma\colon I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular curve, i.e. $C^{\infty}$ and $|\gamma'(t)|\neq 0$ for all $t\in I$. The trace of the curve $\gamma(I)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ we endow it with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus it will be Hausdorff and second countable. My problem is with the property of being locally Euclidean. A regular curve is allowed to have self intersections, for example, the curve $\gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\gamma(t)=(t^{3}-4t,t^2-4)$, has the following graph

[image]

So for example we would have to find an open set that is of the form an open ball $B(a,r)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ intersect with $\gamma(I)$, containing $(0,0)$, such that there is a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}$. We would have something like a curved $X$ around $(0,0)$. How is that homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? Intuitively I understand that around each point on the trace (not one of this singular points) we can find an open set in that topology that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. I would appreciate your help to clarify this doubt I have.

Comment: You are correct. A regular curve only is a $1$-dimensional manifold when it has no self-intersection. It is an *immersed submanifold*, however.

Comment: Also, assuming $I$ is a closed interval, an embedded regular curve is only a submanifold with boundary.

Comment: Further, the image of a smooth regular _bijection_ need not be a one-manifold; a classic example is$$\gamma(t) = (\sin t, \sin t\cos t),\quad 0 < t < 2\pi,$$which is a figure-8. <> In any case, to me a regular curve is a _mapping_ while a manifold is a _set_, so saying one is the other sounds ... informal.

Comment: In the example curve, the derivative is zero when t=0, so, the example curve is not regular.